# My DNS zone includes a loopback record - do I need it?

Tags: dns, localhost, loopback

My dns zone contains a loopback:

```
localhost IN A 127.0.0.1
```

Do I need it, and if so why? I can't think of a reason to have it here, especially as - without a dot - it would be `localhost.example.com`

Comment: Curious, I have the same on _all_ my domains. I use a similar record to access my local test server... `local IN A 192.168.1.13` - avoids the need to edit the local hosts file and works for all machines on the network. Is this related?

Comment: Not in my case - we use `example.local` and `example.internal` as tlds - in the question `localhost` is a subdomain

Comment: The same question was asked on ServerFault a while back: http://serverfault.com/questions/120769/localhost-in-a-dns-zone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer on ServerFault explains what this localhost entry is for https://serverfault.com/questions/120769/localhost-in-a-dns-zone

> `localhost.example.com` is sometimes included on internal DNS servers to prevent "localhost" requests leaking out to the internet (for the case where John Smith types `http://localhost/` in his browser & for whatever reason his resolver doesn't look in the hosts file, appends his search path (example.com) & starts asking name servers what that resolves to).

It also talks about the possibility that such a DNS record could be use for Cross Site Scripting (XSS) attacks and suggest removing it for that reason.

Answer (score 2):

Did your DNS undergo testing because a many times loopback entry tests ability to process Web requests without actually sending any messages out. I believe it is not needed.